# Service Kotlin Android

Tags: kotlin

Actualmente tengo el siguiente Service:

```
class SampleForegroundService : Service() {

private val mHandler = Handler()
companion object {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    lateinit var mCs108Library4a: Cs108Library4A
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    lateinit var sharedObjects: SharedObjects
    lateinit var mSensorConnector: SensorConnector
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    if (intent?.action != null && intent.action.equals(
            ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND, ignoreCase = true
        )
    ) {
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }
    mHandler.post(runnableConfiguring)
    generateForegroundNotification()
    return START_STICKY

}
```

Esto tiene  variables como mCs108Library4a y sharedObjects, que mantiene en memoria valores en arrays etc,

Cuando mi actividad se reinicia, mi service en primero plano si esta corriendo pero los valores que tenia mi service de estas varaibles sharedObjects se pierden por completo,

Esto funciona asi y de ser asi como se pdoria resolver?,

Comment: Cual es el código y donde lo mandas llamar para guarda sharedObjects

Comment: si esta "dentro de un service"  no guarda los datos que estan "en memoria" dentro de la clase service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores en variables de tu aplicación actualmente se pueden perder si el sistema operativo requiere memoria para otros procesos, para mantener la información puedes usar algún método que persista los valores, ya sea un archivo, una base de datos, preferencias.

Por ejemplo, si usas `SharedPreferences` en Kotlin, usa la dependencia:

```
 implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
```

Realiza dos funciones, una para guardar el valor en la preferencia:

```
fun setValue(ctx: Context?, valor: String) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putString("myvalue", valor).apply()
}
```

y otra para obtener el valor de preferencias:

```
fun getValue(ctx: Context?): String{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt("myvalue", "")
}
```